# Paypal We are unable to complete your request at this time. Please try again later. We apologize for the inconvenience

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am attempting PayPal's express checkout this week for an online system I am building. I am running a LAMP server hosted on Koding.com(A virtual machine service) and they have no "web admin" panel. When I attempted the sandbox integration using the appropriate API URLs and API Username, Password, and Signature, it worked fine. No problems. However, when I decided to go live, using the appropriate URLs and API Username, Password, and Signature, I get the following error on the PayPal page:

```
We are unable to complete your request at this time. Please try again later. We apologize for the inconvenience.
```

[image: screenshot]

To answer common questions, I have:

- Switched API Urls to paypal.com vs sandbox.paypal.com
- Tried deleting old API info and replacing it with new Username, Password, and Signature
- Contacted PayPal support, and created a ticket.
- Switched between selling "Physical" and "Digital" goods, to no avail
- My account is a PayPal "business" account.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. When going live with PayPal, you have to go into the PayPal developer portal and create a new application and get it approved because you're working with real money. Silly me.